# TypeError: this.state.tickets.map is not a function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show some tickets info from an api but for some reason maping isnt working

```
class Tickets extends React.Component {
state = {
tickets: [],
clicked: false,
};
onclicked = () => {
this.setState({ clicked: true });
console.log('helloitsme');


};
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getAllTickets();
      this.setState({ tickets: res });
    } catch (err) {}
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        <section className="container">
          {this.state.tickets.map((ticket) => (
            <div onClick={this.onclicked} key={ticket._id}>
              {this.state.clicked === true && (
                <div className="boxinfo">
                  <h1 className="info">{ticket.date}</h1>
                  <h2 className="info">{ticket.place}</h2>
                  <h3 className="info">{ticket.price}</h3>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </section>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
export default Tickets;
```

I googled and tried changing the state array but nothing works. Should I do a fetch to the api?

Comment: It looks like `await getAllTickets();` is not returning an array. I recommend trying to figure out what it returns. Maybe just `console.log(res)` on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to state only if the response contain some data. Also check if your response from getAllTickets is returning an array or not. If the response is not an array then you are likely to get such errors. Below method works if the response is array and it won't set the state until the response contains some data.

```
class Tickets extends React.Component {
state = {
tickets: [],
clicked: false,
};
onclicked = () => {
this.setState({ clicked: true });
console.log('helloitsme');


};
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getAllTickets();
      if (res) {
        this.setState({ tickets: res });
      }
    } catch (err) {}
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        <section className="container">
          {this.state.tickets.map((ticket) => (
            <div onClick={this.onclicked} key={ticket._id}>
              {this.state.clicked === true && (
                <div className="boxinfo">
                  <h1 className="info">{ticket.date}</h1>
                  <h2 className="info">{ticket.place}</h2>
                  <h3 className="info">{ticket.price}</h3>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </section>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
export default Tickets;
```

Also check if you response contains some other data which is an array. In such case if you get res.data as an array, following code works for you.

```
class Tickets extends React.Component {
state = {
tickets: [],
clicked: false,
};
onclicked = () => {
this.setState({ clicked: true });
console.log('helloitsme');


};
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await getAllTickets();
      if (data) {
        this.setState({ tickets: data });
      }
    } catch (err) {}
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        <section className="container">
          {this.state.tickets.map((ticket) => (
            <div onClick={this.onclicked} key={ticket._id}>
              {this.state.clicked === true && (
                <div className="boxinfo">
                  <h1 className="info">{ticket.date}</h1>
                  <h2 className="info">{ticket.place}</h2>
                  <h3 className="info">{ticket.price}</h3>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </section>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
export default Tickets;
```